# AngularJS - updating 'self' value programmatically via a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry in advance, I am not sure the best way to describe this, or title this question. My code should hopefully explain what I am trying to achieve

I have an array of listings that is looped through in the view 'ng-repeat'.  Each one can get updated individually via a function (called by clicking on a button for that listing), but that function just knows about the currently clicked on listing (it is past in as a param). 
The function should change the value of that listing in the view.

eg:

The JS:

```
.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $location, $ionicPopup, Service) { 
    var self = this;
    self.listings  = response.data.items.hits.hits; //Array of listings
    ....
    self.watchlist = function(listing) { //Update individual listing value
       ....
       if (listing.in_watchlist) {
           listing.in_watchlist = 0; //want this to update the actual matching listing in 'self.listings'
       } else {
           listing.in_watchlist = 1; //want this to update the actual matching listing in 'self.listings'
       }
       ....
```

The HTML:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="listing in search.listings">
    In watchlist: {{listing.in_watchlist}}<br/>  
    <button class="button button-block button-balanced ion-star" ng-click="search.watchlist(listing);"></button>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: First you should not use `{{` & `}}` in HTML. It should be `search.watchlist(listing)`

Comment: Thanks for the pickup, fixed that. Though the initial question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem seems to be the Expression inside of the `ng-click` directive.

Try to remove th curly bracets in your `ng-click` like this: `ng-click="search.watchlist(listing);"`

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16609/) with a working example of what you tried: